# Wordpress Contact form 7 - dropdown issue due to too many options

Tags: wordpress, forms, drop-down-menu, contacts

I've been encountering an error when having too many options in a drop down. It simply freezes if there are over 222 options.

I'm running on PHP 5.3.5, but this also happens when running on PHP 5.3.13. Curiously, this issue DOES NOT happen when using 5.2.27.

I've been trying to back trace the error, and I believe it's got something to do with the preg_replace_callback() function called inside do_shortcode () in /includes/shortcodes.php on row 62.

Has any of you encountered the same issue, and do you happen to know how to solve it?

Thanks